# Maximum Order Amount Limit Periodical

Tags: magento-1.8, module, php, magento-community

How can I limit the maximum order amount every 3 months ? I tried using this one (https://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/) but its for every order, and I wanted to only be able to buy x$ every 3 months.

Really need help with this one :(

Comment: The 3 months interval you say, is it fixed? Or dynamic? How you keep track of it?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom report that summarize customer's orders purchased quantities in the last 3 months or for every 3 months. If I remember correctly in the report model/resource you can easily define the time frame. In the database you can find examples of tables used for default reports: `*_aggregated_*`.
And patch a data retrieval code (collection filtered by current customer id) in the example you've saw. Finnaly, add a condition based on what is in the row from the report.

Create a custom report:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030255/how-to-create-a-report-in-magento

The important part is to have the data in a table and refresh it via cron every night. The admin controller is not the issue here.

Comment: But I need to create an extension, is there any way to edit that extension, I think it could help me a lot.

Comment: Try custom report extension. Maybe this: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/advanced-reports.html I see there is "Sales by Product". You don't have to implement a extension (a rich feature module). You just need a custom module for a new report.

Comment: But I dont want to buy an extension, but create one or edit this one since already does something that I need :/